# How to update tensorflow to support tf.contrib?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I want use initializers and batch_norm in tf.contrib module, but my program says can't find it. I re-install tensorflow still can't use tf.contrib module. Can  anyone tell me why?

Comment: Which tensorflow version `print(tf.__version__)` do you have?

Comment: I try this command and got:  'module' object has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: I found it. Version 2.0. Did I install wrong?

Comment: `0.9.0rc0` is the latest version. I guess you have `0.2.X`? Where did you find the version?

Comment: From __init__.py at tensorflow folder

Comment: Which operating system (OS) do you have?

Comment: Linux version 3.13.0-24-generic.

Comment: Have you named your file as tensorflow.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you did, but you certainly don't have the latest Tensorflow version from Google. You should follow [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html) to install it.

To sum it up:

1. Make sure you have the dependencies: `sudo apt-get install python-pip python-dev`
2. Uninstall whatever you have right now: `pip uninstall tensorflow`
3. Set up variables:

Choose the correct one:

```
# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 2.7
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 2.7 
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 3.4
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.4 
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, CPU only, Python 3.5
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl

# Ubuntu/Linux 64-bit, GPU enabled, Python 3.5 
# Requires CUDA toolkit 7.5 and CuDNN v4. For other versions, see "Install from sources" below.
$ export TF_BINARY_URL=https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow-0.9.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

4. Install it

Choose the correct one:

```
# Python 2
$ sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL

# Python 3
$ sudo pip3 install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
```

Comment: I use anaconda install again and succeed. thank you!